# Restarting the Iphone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I need to restart my application on click of a button or by clicking on alert view button. 
how can i do it can anybody share the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot do that. Apple won't let you programmatically restart an iPhone application. You have to instruct the user to do it and he will choose if he will or not restart the application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restarting the Iphone Application to get the xml from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159945/restarting-the-iphone-application-to-get-the-xml-from-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Apple also discourage apps that suggest that they work better if you restart the device, so I think you may be on thin ice even if you ask your user to restart your app.

In short: I think you need to find a way to implement your use case without restarting the app.